# Renew JPanel from a CardLayout

Tags: java, swing, class, jpanel, cardlayout

I am using a `CardLayout` that displays a `JPanel` from another class:

```
card.add("ReadMsg Card", new ReadMessage(id, type, sender));
cl.show(card, "ReadMsg Card");
```

How do I renew/remove the "ReadMsg Card" panel from the layout because the variables `id, type, sender` are remaining the same once added?

Answer (score 0):

You maintain a reference to the `ReadMessage` panel (as an instance field) and either remove it from the container as usual or simply update the properties using `setters`

Comment: the code above is in a ActionListener. nor Remove nor setters are working for me here.

Comment: Unless you have a reference to what was previously set to use the `"ReadMsg Card"` card, you can't remove it or access in any other way...You need to maintain a reference to the `ReadMessage` panel which is currently assigned to the `"ReadMsg Card"` card and use it when want to remove it from the container